# redux store is not rendered on deleting item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I'm new to react hooks. I need help in re-rendering the store (from redux) after deleting items from it. The deleted item is removed from the redux store, but it doesn't render unless I reload the page. I used `window.location.reload(false)`, but I need an alternative that wont require page reload. Help is so much appreciated.

**reducers**

```
case "REMOVE_POST": {
      const deletePost = [
        ...state.posts.filter(item => item.id !== actions.posts.id)
      ];
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: deletePost
      };
    }
```

**component**

```
import { store } from "../../store";

...

const PostsComponent = () => {
  const storedPosts = store.getState();
  const updatedPosts = storedPosts.posts.posts;

 const deletePost = id => {
    store.dispatch({
      type: "REMOVE_POST",
      posts: { id }
    });
return updatedPosts;
  };
}

...

<button
  onClick={() => {
    deletePost(post.id);
    // window.location.reload(false);
  }}
 >
   close
</button>
```

Comment: how do you get `store` variable(and why not `useDispatch()`?)? do you retrieve data with `useSelector` or somehow else?

Comment: Please make a producible example

Comment: @skyboyer Thanks for response. I didn't user ```useDispatch()```nor  ```useSelector() ```

Comment: please append that to your post instead of comment. Also where `store` is coming from? you did not answer that

Comment: @skyboyer .  The ```store``` is from redux store through redux's ```createStore```. I hope i understand what you mean.

Comment: Deleted post gets deleted from store, but it only renders after a page reload.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. The question wasn't formatted correctly. I wasn't referring to redux, but to re-render the state after an action. I realise the state in the component was not included. Simply including useState helped.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you cannot access store by just `import`ing it. Or more precisely if you `import` it directly you should manually `subscribe()` for its changes and `unsubsrcibe()` on unmount(to prevent memory leaks).

You better follow guides and [official docs](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/accessing-store) and either use [`connect()` HOC](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect) or [`useSelector` hook](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector). Then your component will re-render automatically after changes in the store.